# InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type 'System.DateTimeOffset' to type 'System.String'

Tags: razor, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

```
    <input asp-for="Created" class="form-control" />

    [Bind("ID,Author,Created,Image")]

    [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMMM yyyy}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = false)]
    public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }
```

When I remove Bind It works. Also empty strings is works. I try to add input type="text" and format datetime

Comment: Did you try to change `DateTimeOffset` to `DateTimeOffset?` ?

Comment: Did you mean DataType.DateTime?

Comment: No, i mean did you try to change the property `public DateTimeOffset Created { get; set; }` to `public DateTimeOffset? Created { get; set; }`.

Comment: I change it. Also remove required attribute. It is same

Comment: Actually your code should work(i tested it and i haven't got any error), i suspect there is another problem causes error.

Comment: [StringLength(64, MinimumLength = 5, ErrorMessage = This line creates problem Thank you for help